# Anomalous modelsim output, when to ignore, when to fix?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, integrated-circuit

im in the process of designing a few digital circuits, and have experienced a small bug with my state machine.

Looking at the modelsim output we see:

[image]

The small 6000ps pulse should not be there. But I have reason to believe there is something more sinister going on.

For example, looking at what drives the `iLoad1 signal (which is the one causing me errors)

[image]

so here we can clearly see iLoad = (s0)(!s1)(s2), however looking at the model sim output, the three traces above iLoad, s0, s1 and s2 are all logic 0 when iLoad is asserted. So, clearly iLoad should also be zero.
The only additional information I can give is that both the NAND and inverter have a 1ns propagation delay.

Could anyone perhaps explain why I'm seeing this anomaly - should it be ignored if its only 6000picos long?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think anyone could explain. Not without the sources, at least. But I'll suggest one thing to check : race conditions. Are you changing these signals in the same delta cycle as the clock,  ahead of it, or after it, or all in different delta cycles?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It looks like a combinatorial circuit producing a glitch, as combinatorial circuits do. That's one of the things synchronous logic is there to solve. But there's no information to go on so impossible to answer. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: To analyze, one must look in the analog domain of the circuit with all impedance of the driver and load. With RLC factors, one can generate ringing to cross the switching threshold at the half maximum transition frequency. Here 6ns might imply a 12ns cycle resonance or 80MHz resonance, but without all your analog parameters impossible from here to analyze. The answer lies in these details, I believe, however I have no experience in Modelsim. otherwise you may be experiencing a race condition.